# How to change SMTP username in mandrill

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I am using Mandripp app by Mail chimp.

https://mandrillapp.com

For sending emails using there SMTP settings.

I have a SMTP username which I want to change. But Mandrill is not giving me any option to change my SMTP username. It only gives option to change the Username or password for login account but not for SMTP

Can anyone have idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem with Mandrill the default username generated by Mandrill had spaces in it. The program I was using wouldn't allow me to enter spaces in the Username for the SMTP settings. Both the answers above say the username doesn't really matter, but I couldn't get it work without providing the correct username. In the end I created a sub-account with a new name that didn't have spaces and it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

The SMTP username is the same as the account username for login, so you can change that if you want and the SMTP username will also change. With SMTP, no validation actually happens on the username you provide—just the SMTP password (API key) so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having this problem you need to change your contact information through your Mailchimp account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here are the steps to update the username now. You need to do it on Mailchimp (not Mandrill):

1. Log-in on **Mailchimp**
2. Go to Settings > Details
3. There you have a `Account name` field, change it and save
4. Log-in on **Mandrill**
5. Go to Settings > SMTP & API Info
6. There you'll see the updated `SMTP Username`

Answer (score 0):

Click on Account > Username & Contact info.

There you can choose to change username and/or contact email. As @terrorbox mentioned, changing the username does not matter for external API access as it is not checked.

[image: screenshot of username & contact info page]